# Why can't I view a folder in the Files navigator, when permissions are 766, owned by me?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

I have the following mounted drive:

```
caleb@ubuntu-box:/media/data/plex$ ll
total 20
drwxrwxrw-  5 caleb caleb 4096 Jul 11 13:29 ./
drwx------  3 caleb caleb 4096 Jul 10 19:48 ../
drwxrwxrw-  4 caleb caleb 4096 Jul  6 20:43 Fitness/
drwxrwxrw- 18 caleb caleb 4096 Jul 10 19:48 Movies/
drwxrwxrw-  3 caleb caleb 4096 Jul 10 19:52 Shows/
```

However, when I try to navigate to these files graphically using the `Files` browser, I get an error when I try to open, which shows a message `You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of "Shows"`. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you check to make sure the file navigator running with your EUID? (=as the caleb user)